# Load spring xml configuration according the profile

Tags: java, spring, xml-configuration, spring-profiles

I know that I can load  application context from xml file like this:

```
ApplicationContext app = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/applicationContext.xml");
```

But in my case it is irrelevent.

inside the `applicationContext.xml` I use profiles.

How can I load context according the profile ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the profile via an JVM property

> -Dspring.profiles.active=YOUR_PROFILE_NAMES_AS_COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST

Then Application Context gets created with beans which you have activated
using JVM property